# C Programming - passing variable argument to opendir

Tags: c, variables, arguments, opendir

I'm trying to do this:

```
const char *p = "/home/paul";
dp = opendir(*p);
```

But that fails with the following error:

> passing argument 1 of 'opendir' makes pointer from integer without a
>   cast

I'm at a loss here, as far as I know what I'm attempting is perfectly valid. After all, I'm passing a *const char* to a function who's input is a *const char*.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

The [`opendir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/opendir.html) function accepts a `const char *` argument, but you're sending it a `const char`. `*p` [dereferences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator) the value pointed to by `p`, and returns the first character in the array, which is "`/`". So the result of `*p` is the `const char` value "`/`".

`p` however *is* a `const char *`, so change that to:

```
dp = opendir(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing because you are going indirect through p:

dp = opendir(*p);

Because opendir takes a char * as an argument, and you are telling opendir to look for that char * in the spot where p is pointing, opendir is using "/home/paul" as its char *.

But p is the exact value opendir wants. Instead, say:

dp = opendir(p);

and everything will be smooth as glass.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char *p = "/home/paul";
dp = opendir(*p);
```

the declaration const char *p = "/home/paul"; means that 'p' is pointing to the start of the string where p is essentially an address in memory where the string is.

when you write *p it means you are accessing the content of where p points which is the first character in the string, namely '/'